Generating a Microsoft Word report from data in Microsoft Azure SQL Server
I need to generate a Word document report from data in an Azure SQL Server database.
This will involve creating nicely formatted tables in Word from some of the data.
The goal is to create a Word based report containing various tables using data from the database. A partner company will then be able to download this Word document, add specific text and a conclusion, and then send this out to the customer.
Is there a Microsoft or Azure service or another software product we can use to achieve this?

There are a few ways:
From the Azure Portal you can use these 3 options:

From there you can:

Create Power BI reports (and then export them in CSV or PDF)
Import the data to Power Apps (but that would be more for creating apps)
Import the data to Power Automate (and maybe there you can export to Microsoft Word)

Otherwise directly from Microsoft Excel you can go to Data > Get Data > From Azure > From Azure SQL Database

This way you would be able to export to Excel. From there you can now import to Word.
There is no direct link from Microsoft Word to Azure SQL Database.
Maybe if you tell us what is your goal we can find a better solution. What are you supposed to do then with those data in the Word file? Do you want to invoice people?

This was a good answer thank you. Very good point about the goal, I have updated my question. From what I am reading in the answer, it seems that the most effective way is to generate an Excel file with all the specific data, then import to Word.
